# Entire Pandas Column Read in as NAN from read_csv()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having trouble reading in my CSV file with Pandas. It's reading in a stock dataset which contains the Date and OHLCV columns, but for some reason, it's reading in the Open column as all Nan's.

I've read in other posts that this could be a "non-UTF-8" encoding issue, so I've since re-encoded it to UTF-8 via the Notepad++ route, but still the same problem. When I print the `dtypes` of the columns, they all say `float64` (except for volume as those are integers) which is good, so why would I be getting all nan's for the `Open` column, if they ARE `float64`'s?

To reproduce, download the dataset I'm using from my [google drive link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TuUmnLr_8lQ8beZFDahjMGEsC07bJEO1/view?usp=sharing), and then place it in the same folder as this below minimal example script. I imagine it's got something to do with this dataset, but I've used it elsewhere without this issue before:

```
from pandas import read_csv, to_datetime

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                            Import/Prepare Dataset                            #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Read in df
datapath = "./SPY5min.csv"
df = read_csv(datapath)
df['time'] = to_datetime(df['time'])
# Rename the columns
df = df.rename(columns={"time": "Datetime",
                        "open":" Open",
                        "high": "High",
                        "low": "Low",
                        "close": "Close",
                        "volume": "Volume"})
# Set the index
df = df.set_index("Datetime")
# For some reason, "Open" isn't being recognized as a column,
# so using this below fix to make it "seen" (though I suspect
# this is where the problem originates)
df = df.reindex(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
# Preview the dtypes of the columns
print(df.dtypes)
# Attempt at a fix to convert open column to float64, same as the
# others
df['Open'] = df['Open'].astype('float64')
print(df.isnull().sum())
# ------------------------ End Import/Prepare Dataset ------------------------ #
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TuUmnLr_8lQ8beZFDahjMGEsC07bJEO1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I got [normal values](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MkjHC0jqfxRDfclwPWJO3gUGRXHHJr1o/view?usp=sharing). Am I right that you want to import a csv file & just rename columns?

Comment: `... "open":" Open", ...` should be `... "open":"Open" ...` (there's a blank before `Open`).

Comment: @Timus UGH. I’m just blind. Thank you. If you post this as an answer I’ll mark it as completed

Comment: All good, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a space before `Open` in your `df.rename` code, e.g. `" Open"` which should be `"Open"`

Comment: Don't think it matters but `LLooks` should probably be changed to `Looks`